# How to properly install pyclewn for VIM?

Tags: macos, debugging, vim

I am interested in improving my workflow, and was hoping to add clewn or pyclewn so I could do debugging in vim. I am using Mac OS X 10.8. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it installed with the basic instructions. I run the instuctions on this page: http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/install.html
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyclewn/

```
mbp:pyclewn-1.10.py2 nate$ python setup.py install --force
Failed to run 'gvim' as Vim.
Please set the EDITOR environment variable or run 'pyclewn --editor=/path/to/(g)vim'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 48, in <module>
    vimdir = pyclewn_install.vimdir()
  File "/Users/nate/Downloads/pyclewn-1.10.py2/clewn/misc.py", line 85, in _dec
ret = f(*args)
  File "/Users/nate/Downloads/pyclewn-1.10.py2/pyclewn_install.py", line 49, in vimdir
    path = vim.exec_vimcmd(['echon $VIM'])
  File "/Users/nate/Downloads/pyclewn-1.10.py2/clewn/vim.py", line 96, in exec_vimcmd
subprocess.Popen(args).wait()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I try to do as it suggests by setting the EDITOR variable:

```
mbp:pyclewn-1.10.py2 nate$ EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
mbp:pyclewn-1.10.py2 nate$ echo $EDITOR
/usr/bin/vim
```

...But I get the same error again. I get the same error if I try to use the Python 3 version of pyclewn as well.

Trying to run the other suggested command gives another error:

```
mbp:pyclewn-1.10.py2 nate$ ./pyclewn --editor=/usr/bin/vim
vim  CRITICAL 
Exception in pyclewn:

<class 'clewn.ClewnError'>
"pyclewn.vim version does not match pyclewn's:
    pyclewn version: "pyclewn-1.10.py2"
    pyclewn.vim version: """
source line: "% (pyclewn_version, version))"
at /Users/nate/Downloads/pyclewn-1.10.py2/clewn/vim.py:383
pyclewn aborting...
```

Any ideas? I don't know enough about this kind of stuff to help fix it, unfortunately. The project is hosted on sourceforge, and I can't figure out how to report a bug there, so I'm posting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, I am an idiot. Having not exported the EDITOR variable, it was invisible to the python script. So, for those of you that have this error, you need to do:

```
$ EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
$ echo $EDITOR
/usr/bin/vim
$ export EDITOR
```

For me it seems that my version of vim does have `netbeans_intg` and `autocmd` support (required for pyclewn). It does not have `python3` support. You can figure this out by typing `vim --version`. I am not sure if at some point in the past I replaced the version of vim that comes with OS X, or if that is how it comes now. I don't know why I would have modified/replaced the `/usr/bin/` version, so I assume it is now standard that way. Hopefully this works for others.

Answer (score 1):

I have no practical experience with pyclewn but a few things are relatively obvious from your question:

- You are using the default Vim that comes with Mac OS X. AFAIK, it doesn't come either with Python support or with the netbeans interface. Basically, there's no way to get a working pyclewn install (let alone a convincing editing environment) that way. I'd suggest you get a proper Vim build like MacVim which, AFAIK, comes with all you need. Assuming you have moved the bundled `mvim` script somewhere in your `$PATH`, you'll probably be able to run `pyclewn --editor=/path/to/mvim`.
- While you *can* install a GTK-based GVim on a Mac under X11, I don't believe you should take that route. This would give you a proper `gvim` command but you would probably loose on other fronts.

Comment: Thanks for the input, you make good points. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Setting editor to mvim still returns the exact same error for the first case. Doing pyclewn --editor=/path/to/mvim gives a different but similar error as before. :-/. Regarding the first error, I've tried to search the source code to understand why it's looking for gvim, but just can't figure it out yet. I'll keep at it, get to the bottom. Thanks again.

Comment: pyclewn needs a Vim built with the netbeans interface, that's why it looks for a `gvim`. Try creating a symlink?

Comment: If you're using [homebrew](http://brew.sh), I would suggest installing mvim via `brew install mvim` and then symlinking `gvim` to it.