# How to install pyclewn for VIM on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim

By instructions on this page:

http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/install.html

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyclewn/

I downloaded the pyclewn 1.8 (py2) and unzip to ~/pyclewn1.8

Then I ran

```
sudo python setup.py install --force
```

But I got the following errors:

```
Failed to run 'gvim' as Vim.
Please set the EDITOR environment variable or run 'pyclewn

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 46, in <module>
    vimdir = pyclewn_install.vimdir()
  File "/home/azureuser/pyclewn1.8/clewn/misc.py", line 85
    ret = f(*args)
  File "/home/azureuser/pyclewn1.8/pyclewn_install.py", li
    path = vim.exec_vimcmd(['echon $VIM'])
  File "/home/azureuser/pyclewn1.8/clewn/vim.py", line 96,
    subprocess.Popen(args).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I used the google and stackoverflow to search and found only one document:

[How to properly install pyclewn for VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986970/how-to-properly-install-pyclewn-for-vim)

Refer to the link above, I tried to set EDITOR=$HOME/.vim, VIM=$HOME/.vim and vimdir=$HOME/.vim, and export all of them, ran the setup.py again as above, but got the same errors.

My OS is Ubuntu

```
Linux auser 3.13.0-40-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 13 17:53:56 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Python version is 2.7.6

vi version is

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
```

And I checked it seems that I have installed related component netbeans.

```
apt-cache pkgnames | grep netbeans
libnetbeans-cvsclient-java
netbeans
```

So far, I have no idea on continue to install pyclewn.

Any idea will be much appreciated. thx a lot.

Comment: Do you have GVim on your system? AFAIK pyclewn won't run with Vim.

Comment: @romainl, No, I don't use GVim. I use tool putty remote to my azure VM machine (Ubuntu). From your comment, it seems that VIM can't work with pyclewn... T_T